# A proper term for equivalence relation with a finite quotient set

Tags: equivalence-relations

Is there a proper term for an equivalence relation $\sim$ on some set $M$ such that it partitions $M$ into finitely many equivalence classes? *Finite* equivalence relation? or *co-finite*? or equivalence relation *of finite rank*? or *of finite index*?

Comment: I've never run across a term, but *finite index* sounds good, based on the analogy with group theory.

Comment: Thanks, *finite index* sounds reasonable. I thought about group theory, too.